# Calculate the integral of $\sqrt{x}(1-x)$

Tags: integration

I'm having trouble calculating the integral of $\sqrt{X}(1-x)$ with substitution.

The steps which I have so far:

$$\sqrt{x} (1-x)dx \quad \{u=\sqrt{x}, du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\}$$

$$2 \int -u^2(u^{2}-1)du$$

$$-2 \int u^2(u^{2}-1)du$$

Could someone please help me calculate this integral using substitution?

Comment: Maybe you get more answers if you have a look at the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: After substitution, you can expand the polynomial and integration is immediate.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the $f$ is supposed to be, but if it's supposed to be an integral, please use `\int`.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I edited the question thank you!

Comment: There should be a $dx$ somewhere so you know what to substitute away

Comment: As Miguel says, just distribute to get$$u^2(u^2-1)=u^4-u^2$$and apply the power rule.

Comment: The integrand is $x^{1/2}-x^{3/2}$ and can be integrated much more quickly without substitution.

Comment: @Aretino I agree but I'm required to work this out with substitution. I've been stuck now for 4 hours and I don't see how I can fix this.

Comment: When you figure out what $du$ should be, there should be a $dx$ somewhere in that expression or you can't continue. Also there must be a $dx$ in the original integral for anything to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Well, substitution isn't much helpful here if you know the anti derivative of ${x}^n $. But still:

Let, $\sqrt{x}=p\implies dx=2p\cdot dp$

$$\int{\sqrt{x}(1-x)}\cdot dx=\int{p(1-p^2)2p\cdot dp}=-2\int{p^4-p^2}=\frac{2p^3}{3}-\frac{2p^5}{5}=\frac{2x\sqrt{x}}{3}-\frac{2x^2\sqrt{x}}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any substitution!

$$\int (1-x)\sqrt{x}\,dx=\int (x^{1/2}-x^{3/2})\,dx=(*)$$

Now remember that, for every $\alpha\ne-1$; $$\int x^\alpha\,dx=\frac{1}{1+\alpha}\,x^{1+\alpha}+C$$

So we have

$$(*)=\dfrac{1}{1+\frac12}\,x^{1+\frac12}-\dfrac{1}{1+\frac32}\,x^{1+\frac32}+C=\dfrac{2}{3}\,x^{\frac32}-\dfrac{2}{5}\,x^{\frac52}+C$$
hence

$$(*)=\dfrac{2}{3}x\sqrt{x}-\dfrac{2}{5}x^2\sqrt{x}+C=\dfrac{2}{15}x\sqrt{x}\left(5-3x \right)+C$$

Comment: I agree that you don't need substitution but I'm required to

Comment: Hope it can be useful anyway. I do math not homeworks :)

Comment: It's not homework, it's trying to get better at math ;-)

Comment: That's wonderful! You'll appreciate my simple and elegant and modest solution ... :))

Comment: Please learn to use `$$...$$` instead of `$...$` and `\frac` instead of `\dfrac` (which is very rarely needed).